# Reason of using omm in mantra?

Tags: mantras, om

Why is omm used before every mantra to please lord? e.g. Why is omm used before namoh bhagawate rudraya. i understand the latter words like namoh = namaste/bow, bhagawate = bhagawan, rudraya = rudra. but reason of using omm? As I've understood omm represents the sound of universe, sound of god himself, vibration frequency which is somehow related to everything don't know how.

Comment: Not in every mantra is used. Mahamantras do not have OM. But OM is PRANAVA. First manifested .